# Indexing lists of list/vectors

Tags: r, list

**Data**

```
lst <- list(1, 1:3, 2:4)
ind <- c(1, 2, 2)
```

**Problem**

I can guarantee that `length(ind) == length(lst)` and now I want to get the 1st element of the the first element of `lst`, then the second element of the second element and finally the second element of the third element.

With a loop I could do something like

```
sapply(seq_along(ind), function(i) lst[[i]][[ind[i]]])
```

So my question is whether I need the loop or is there any smart indexing technique which I am not aware of? Background of the question is that I have the impression that I do not make best use of `R's`  capability to do incredible stuff with smart indexing (like indexing a matrix with another matrix).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `mapply` to get the corresponding element of 'lst' based on the index in 'ind'.

```
mapply(`[`, lst, ind)
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Beautiful! +1 Was looking as simple as that, thanks!